# Fetch all the rows in a data frame matching with rows of other data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have 2 data frames, say

```
df1 = data.frame(A = c(10,20,30,20,10),B = c("a","b","c","b","a"))
df2 = data.frame(A = c(10,30),B = c("a","c"))
```

Now I want all rows in df1 matching with rows of df2. Here, the answer should be:

```
>dfout
  A  B
1 10 a
2 30 c
3 10 a
```

If I use:

```
sqldf("select * from df1 intersect select * from df2")
```

I get:

```
>output
  A  B
1 10 a
2 30 c
```

But I want all the matching rows including duplicates.

**Note:** The solution I request should be a generalized one, without using column names anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`merge` seems to be the guy for the job:

```
merge(df1, df2)

##    A B
## 1 10 a
## 2 10 a
## 3 30 c
```

Alternatively, `inner_join` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df1, df2)

## Joining by: c("A", "B")
##    A B
## 1 10 a
## 2 30 c
## 3 10 a
## Warning message:
## In inner_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
##   joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using a natural join using the default backend (sqlite) of sqldf:

```
sqldf("SELECT * FROM df1 NATURAL JOIN df2")
```

A natural join will perform an inner join between the two tables (data frames) based on equality conditions between all columns with the same names.

**Note:** It would also be possible to use **INTERSECT ALL** with the RPostgreSQL backend to sqldf.

Comment: sqldf supports 4 different backends.

Comment: True, but by default it uses sqlite.  Additionally, almost all of the others have to be installed separately.  I'll edit the post to mention that, but it is probably safe to assume that the OP is using the default setup.  Plus, as far as I know, none of the backends will support **INTERSECT ALL** except PostgreSQL.

Comment: I have reworded it a bit more positively.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, on=names(df1)]
#    A B
#1: 10 a
#2: 10 a
#3: 30 c
```